# Resizing an array by pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am resizing an array inside of a method, but since I am using a pointer, the memory address is now incorrect.  The `diffDataTot` pointer is initially created in `main()`, and then passed into the `calculateField()` method.  The `calculateField()` method contains new information that needs to be added to `diffDataTot`, and some old information needs to be removed.  I indicated this using the `resize()` method call.

```cpp
void calculateField(diffData* diffDataTot){
    diffData* filler = (diffData*)malloc(newSize * sizeof(diffData));
    filler = resize(newSize, diffDataTot);
    free(diffDataTot);
    diffDataTot = filler;
    free(filler);
}

int main{
    diffData* diffDataTot = (diffData*)malloc(sizeof(diffData));
    calculateField(diffDataTot);
}
```

I had to abbreviate this since it is from a full scale simulation that is thousands of lines.  However, the issue is that `diffDataTot` contains the correct information locally inside of the `calculateField()` method.  But the pointer points to a different address in memory than in `main()`.  I could try without using a pointer, but I would like to avoid copying the entire array every time `calculateField()` is called since it is quite large.

Is there any way for me to pass back the memory of the first element in the array from the `calculateField()` method?

Comment: If this is `c++` changing `void calculateField(diffData* diffDataTot){` to `void calculateField(diffData*& diffDataTot){` should allow the pointer to be changed in the caller. This is the difference between passing the pointer by value and by reference.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the address of your pointer (pointer on pointer).

```
void
resizing_func(int **elements,
              int *elem_count)
{
  //---- get rid of additional indirection ----
  int *p=*elements;
  int count=*elem_count;
  //---- work with local variables ----
  // ...
  int new_count=2*count; // whatever is needed for the problem
  p=realloc(p, new_count*sizeof(int));
  // ...
  //---- make changes visible in calling context ----
  *elements=p;
  *elem_count=new_count;
}

void
testing_func(void)
{
  int count=100;
  int *elements=malloc(count*sizeof(int));
  // populate elements
  resizing_func(&elements, &count);
  // use updated elements and count
}
```

Depending on the problem, `realloc()` can be replaced by:

- allocate a second buffer,
- work with first and second buffer,
- free the first buffer and continue with the second,

as in the OP's question.
(by the way, notice that `free(filler)` will free what was intended to be kept in `diffDataTot`)

note: as the question is tagged `c++`, it would have probably been better to use a `std::vector` and pass it by (non-const) reference; but the provided source code looks like `c`.

Comment: Amazing thanks, this is exactly what I needed.  The code that I am using is definitely c++, but since I hand wrote it to simplify what I am trying to do maybe I changed some syntax